# Freemarker Listing problems from mysql data fetch by Java code

Tags: java, mysql

Good Day everyone I need some help, can anyone help me whats wrong with my code I am a new in Freemarker and Java. as of now Im using java to fetch data from MySQL and to be displayed by FTL.

here is my code:

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM aprfreq";
             Statement st = conn.createStatement();
             ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);
             int i =0; // this variable used to be the extension for the new key  
                     Map<String, Collection<String>> prfdata = new HashMap<String, Collection<String>>();
             List<Map<String, Collection<String>>> value = new ArrayList<Map<String, Collection<String>>>();
               while (rs.next())
                  {      
                 String prfn = rs.getString("prfn");
                 String md = rs.getString("md");
                 String prfdn = rs.getString("prfdn");
                  prfdata.put("keys"+i, Arrays.asList(prfn,md,prfdn));
                 i = i +1;
                    }
              request.setAttribute("data",prfdata);
```

FTL Line:

```
<#list data?keys as k> 
${data[k][0]}, ${data[k][1]}
</#list>
```

result:

```
Expression data is undefined on line 1, column 8 in component
```

I want a result:
that will lit all the keys like rows in table
:(
I need HELP

Comment: Are you sure that request.setAttribute("data",prfdata); does not do the job of sending  parameters to the Freemarker template? Normally, you pass parameters in a Map and call the method to process the template. Please show that method where the freemarker template is processed.

Comment: if, I will call the data like this
${parameters.data.keys0[0]}
I can get the fetched data that is passed to the parameters.
my problem is how to iterate the parameters.data.keys -> keys0,keys1...
as stated in my code:
 prfdata.put("keys"+i, Arrays.asList(prfn,md,prfdn));

Comment: Your comment and the error suggest that you have to access data through parameters. So something like this: <#list parameters.data?keys as k> 
${data[k][0]}, ${data[k][1]},...
</#list>

Comment: the same error if I will use that line 
*Expression data is undefined on line 2
I want to know if there is a way to iterate the index in FTL

Comment: Yes, according Freemarker documentation (http://freemarker.org/docs/ref_directive_list.html#autoid_95), you can get the index with item?index for Freemarker 2.3.23 or above and with item_index with earlier Freemarker.